# Websphere JVM argument in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jvm, websphere, jvm-arguments

I am trying to get some properties imported in JVM by changing "Server" file from the bin folder of WS. The guide I am following is made for Windows and it says to do so:

```
if not defined WLP_SKIP_MAXPERMSIZE (
  set JVM_OPTIONS=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Durl.soap.configuration="C:\WAS8551\wlp\usr\servers\server1\properties\wsserver.properties"
) else (
  set JVM_OPTIONS= -Durl.soap.configuration="C:\WAS8551\wlp\usr\servers\server1\properties\wsserver.properties"
)
```

In Ubuntu I changed my "Server" from

```
if [ -z "${WLP_SKIP_MAXPERMSIZE}" ]; then
  SERVER_JVM_OPTIONS_QUOTED="${SERVER_JVM_OPTIONS_QUOTED} -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
fi
```

to

```
if [ -z "${WLP_SKIP_MAXPERMSIZE}" ]; then
  SERVER_JVM_OPTIONS_QUOTED="${SERVER_JVM_OPTIONS_QUOTED} -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
  -Durl.soap.configuration=/home/danilo/Links/CSE/wlp/usr/servers/server1/properties/wsserver.properties"
else SERVER_JVM_OPTIONS_QUOTED="${SERVER_JVM_OPTIONS_QUOTED} 
  -Durl.soap.configuration=/home/danilo/Links/CSE/wlp/usr/servers/server1/properties/wsserver.properties"
fi
```

but if i try to run ./server run server1 I obtain this

```
./server: 2: eval: -Durl.soap.configuration=/home/danilo/Links/CSE/wlp/usr/servers/server1/properties/wsserver.properties: not found
```

The path is correct, cause if I run gedit on that path it opens the file. What shoult the problem be?

Comment: Changing the server script for Liberty is not supported. If you merely want to set new jvm options then you should use the jvm.options file, add: -Durl.soap.configuration=/home/danilo/Links/CSE/wlp/usr/servers/server1/properties/wsserver.properties this will have hard coded paths though.

Comment: @Alasdair You should make that an answer with a reference to the "What might be modified by applying service or an upgrade?" section of https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_profile_externals.html

Comment: It worked, thx @Alasdair

Comment: @bkail thanks for the suggestion, I've updated it.

Comment: @Neo87 If your problem is solved, you should click the checkmark next to Alasdair's answer to accept it.  Accepting answers increases the answerer's reputation, and it increases your acceptance rate so that others are more likely to answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the server script for Liberty is not supported. If you merely want to set new jvm options then you should use the jvm.options file, add: -Durl.soap.configuration=/home/danilo/Links/CSE/wlp/usr/servers/server1/properti‌​es/wsserver.properties this will have hard coded paths though.

The [KC documents things that can change between releases](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_profile_externals.html). In general anything outside of usr or etc are changed by fixpacks or iFixes.